# Is $|x-y|^{-a}$ Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]^2$ if $0<a<1$?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I think the following is true but I can not prove it:

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{1}{|x-y|^a}\,dx\,dy<\infty$$

where $dx$ and $dy$ are Lebesgue measures, and $0<a<1$.

If the above integral makes sense as a Riemann integral, it clearly makes sense as a Lebesgue integral too. That said, I am stuck.

Comment: I was going to edit the last sentence but I don't know what it is trying to say.  Oops, then @Jack undid part of my edit of the first sentence.  Jack, it seems you added content to the last sentence that wasn't there.  How did you infer this intent?

Comment: @JonasMeyer: I thought that was the intended meaning of the last paragraph, but if I am wrong, I suggest the OP to perform a rollback or a further edit.

Answer (score 4):

Since we are dealing with a non-negative integrand function, we may simply exploit Fubini's theorem and symmetry (no matter if we are dealing with Lebesgue-integrability or improper Riemann-integrability):
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \iint_{(0,1)^2}\frac{dx\,dy}{|x-y|^a} = 2 \iint_{0<y<x<1}\frac{dx\,dy}{(x-y)^a}&=&2\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{(x-y)^a}\,dy\,dx\\&\stackrel{y\mapsto x(1-t)}{=}&2\iint_{(0,1)^2}\frac{x}{x^at^a}\,dt\,dx\\&=&\frac{2}{(1-a)(2-a)} \end{eqnarray*}$$
which is finite for any $a\in(0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have a more question. 
If dx and dy is the Hausdorff measure with s-dimension, then is the integral ''Hausdorff integrable'' true?.
 For example, it is Hausdorff measure with its dimension be $\log2/\log 3$, and you can see $[0,1]$ looks like the Cantor set.